# How should I construct a SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> from an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>?

Tags: c#

`using System.Collections.Generic;`

Suppose I have an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` (possibly an `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or perhaps the result of a LINQ method chain) and I want to construct a `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` from it. `SortedDictionary` has 4 constructors:

```
public SortedDictionary();
public SortedDictionary(IComparer<TKey>? comparer);
public SortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary);
public SortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey>? comparer);
```

If I had an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` then it would be clear what I should do. But since I have an
`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` instead, there are two approaches I could take.

- I could create a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` using LINQ's `ToDictionary()`, and pass that to one of the `SortedDictionary` constructors that accepts an `IDictionary`. This has the advantage that I will write less code.
- I could create an empty `SortedDictionary` and loop through the `KeyValuePairs` in my `IEnumerable`, adding them to the dictionary. This has the advantage that I don't construct a whole dictionary just for the sake of feeding it to the `SortedDictionary` constructor. But is that important? Is there any performance advantage? Does it depend on whether the `KeyValuePairs` in my `IEnumerable` are sorted (with respect to the `IComparer<TKey>` my `SortedDictionary` will use) or in random order?

What if I wanted to create a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` instead of a `SortedDictionary`? Would the answer be the same?

Comment: [Read the Remarks section for SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-5.0#remarks) - it's optimized for fast random insertion, so initializing empty + add each pair one by one should be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you're over thinking this. Wouldn't this suffice?

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

---

Or, if you prefer, wrap it in an extension method:

```
public static SortedDictionary<K, V> ToSortedDictionary<K, V>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> pairs)
{
    var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<K, V>();
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Then it's just:

```
SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = pairs.ToSortedDictionary();
```

Comment: It only seems over-thought because `SortedDictionary` doesn't offer an obvious constructor.

Comment: This attempt at an answer totally misses the point of the question. I don't believe you read and understood the question before you wrote it.